# Type Error when adding list to adapter - Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add a list to my adapter but got the following error

```
private val repository = Repository()
private var songResources = repository.fetchData()
private var songList = songResources.keys.toMutableList()

adapter.submitList(songList)
```

Error
`Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<String> but (Mutable)List<SongInfo!>? was expected`

Here is my Repository.kt

```
class Repository {
    private var songResources = hashMapOf(
        "Dark Star" to
                SongInfo("Dark Star",
                    R.raw.dark_star_excerpt,
                    "1:30"),
        "What's Mine" to
                SongInfo("What's Mine",
                    R.raw.whats_mine_excerpt,
                    "1:15")
    )
    fun fetchData(): HashMap<String, SongInfo> {
        return songResources
    }
```

I checked using my IDE by printing songList and got.
`[Dark Star, What's Mine]`
Which I wanted.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you please show us your submitList method in adaptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`private var songList = songResources.keys.toMutableList()`

to

```
private var songList = songResources.values.toMutableList()
```

Comment: This works thanks! Last questions, If i want to get the total time of the song what do I need to change?

Comment: You can do it like `songResources.get("Dark Star").duration` (assuming "duration" is the variable name of the duration in SongInfo class)

Comment: Got it. Appreciate your help!